# how to execute powershell script when user logout

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script to upgrade enterprise software. However since if someone singed-in to the computer it is hard to find time to run this script.
Therefore, I have make the script to wait until user logged-out.

I know how to find out if someone is logged into the pc. I need to know how to make powershell script wait until the user logged out.

Comment: Why not set it up as a Scheduled Task at Log Off?

Comment: Or use a [GPO logoff script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789196(v=ws.11)#:~:text=To%20assign%20user%20logoff%20scripts,-Open%20the%20Group&text=Policy%20Management%20Console.-,Right-click%20the%20Group%20Policy%20object%20you%20want%20to%20edit,the%20results%20pane%2C%20expand%20Logoff.)

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) do this using Scheduled Tasks, the event ID for logout should be 4647. Tie your script to this event and it will run when the user logs out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4647

Comment: thanks. for some reason, I can't click on up arrow.